# How to Optimize when Building Dataframe from Lists?

Tags: python, pandas

let's say I want to build a dataframe with the following columns: `city`, `occupation`, `income`, `predicted_rent`. The purpose of this table is to display the predicted rent paid given the variables occupation, income, and city.

Since there are three input variables, I need a row in the table for EACH possible combination of the three variables.

I use a nested for loop. The current method I am using, which gives the desired output:

```
city = [NYC, SF, ...., ...] # len(city) != len(occupation) != len(income)
occupation = [SWE, Doctor, ....]
income = ['<50K', '50-100K', '100-200K', ...]

cities_input = []
occupations_input = []
incomes_input = []
predicted_rents = []
for c in city:
    for o in occupation:
        for i in income:
            rent = predict_rent(c, o, i)
            cities_input.append(c)
            occupations_input.append(o)
            incomes_input.append(i)
            predicted_rents.append(rent)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'city': cities_input,
    'occupation': occupations_input,
    'income': incomes_input, 
    'predicted_rent': predicted_rents})
```

I am able to build the dataframe, but it takes very long.

My exact use case is different from the above, but I will need to compute ~150K rows to take into consideration every combination. My last attempt, it took more than 24 hours.

I cannot use `zip` as `len(city) != len(occupation) != len(income)`

I know nested for loops are not good for speed, can I optimize the code further? Is there a way I dont need to use nested for loops?

Comment: How complex is `predict_rent` definition and how long takes a single run of `predict_rent` function?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it takes 0.3-0.7 seconds but depending on the input it can take longer, but never more than than 1.6 seconds

Comment: Does it still run too long when you apply the proposed `itertools.product` approach ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest on some sample data that i would expect 6840 computations/rows on, using `itertools.product` did not speed up the time taken. (~60mins)

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` is more efficient than nested for loops.

[Link](https://khuyentran1401.github.io/Efficient_Python_tricks_and_tools_for_data_scientists/Chapter2/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import product
# len(city) != len(occupation) != len(income)

city = ['NYC', 'SF'] 
occupation = ['SWE', 'Doctor','Lawyer', 'Nurse']
income = ['<50K', '50-100K', '100-200K']

list(product(city,occupation,income))
#output
[('NYC', 'SWE', '<50K'),
 ('NYC', 'SWE', '50-100K'),
 ('NYC', 'SWE', '100-200K'),
 ('NYC', 'Doctor', '<50K'),
 ('NYC', 'Doctor', '50-100K'),
 ('NYC', 'Doctor', '100-200K'),
 ('NYC', 'Lawyer', '<50K'),
 ('NYC', 'Lawyer', '50-100K'),
 ('NYC', 'Lawyer', '100-200K'),
 ('NYC', 'Nurse', '<50K'),
 ('NYC', 'Nurse', '50-100K'),
 ('NYC', 'Nurse', '100-200K'),
 ('SF', 'SWE', '<50K'),
 ('SF', 'SWE', '50-100K'),
 ('SF', 'SWE', '100-200K'),
 ('SF', 'Doctor', '<50K'),
 ('SF', 'Doctor', '50-100K'),
 ('SF', 'Doctor', '100-200K'),
 ('SF', 'Lawyer', '<50K'),
 ('SF', 'Lawyer', '50-100K'),
 ('SF', 'Lawyer', '100-200K'),
 ('SF', 'Nurse', '<50K'),
 ('SF', 'Nurse', '50-100K'),
 ('SF', 'Nurse', '100-200K')]
```

To convert the above into a dataframe you could use:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(product(city,occupation,income)), columns = ['city', 'occupation', 'income'])
```

Giving

```
   city occupation    income
0   NYC        SWE      <50K
1   NYC        SWE   50-100K
2   NYC        SWE  100-200K
3   NYC     Doctor      <50K
4   NYC     Doctor   50-100K
5   NYC     Doctor  100-200K
6   NYC     Lawyer      <50K
7   NYC     Lawyer   50-100K
8   NYC     Lawyer  100-200K
9   NYC      Nurse      <50K
10  NYC      Nurse   50-100K
11  NYC      Nurse  100-200K
12   SF        SWE      <50K
13   SF        SWE   50-100K
14   SF        SWE  100-200K
15   SF     Doctor      <50K
16   SF     Doctor   50-100K
17   SF     Doctor  100-200K
18   SF     Lawyer      <50K
19   SF     Lawyer   50-100K
20   SF     Lawyer  100-200K
21   SF      Nurse      <50K
22   SF      Nurse   50-100K
23   SF      Nurse  100-200K
```